# PHP svn updating

Tags: php, svn

I am trying to make a svn directory readable through web browsers, so what I do is to checkout it using the svn php extension. I've managed to checkout and update the directory through ssh using the command line php thingy. It works without problems. But if I try to update the directory using a .php-file on the web page, it gives me error code 500. The error logs say this

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to
           undefined function svn_update() in /home/derp/public_html/svn/php/update_svn.php
```

I haven't done much php, and I am not sure how to make this work. Does anyone here know?

Answer (score 2):

You need to have the [PECL extension `svn`](http://pecl.php.net/package/svn) installed for this function to exist in your PHP installation.

Comment: Hmm. Okay. Why does it work when I run the php commands in the interactive php command line, but not through the browser?

Comment: CLI and web sometimes use different `php.ini` files. You may have PECL SVN loaded on one but not the other.

Comment: ah, okay. How would I proceed to install PECL and the svn extension? I've never done this before. I'm running ubuntu.

Comment: Usually in Ubuntu a PECL module would be installed by adding something like `extension=svn.so` to `/etc/php5/conf.d/svn.ini`. Your setup may be custom, though. If there's nothing there, you can always run `pecl install svn`.

Comment: Okay, now I've installed the svn extension, and it doesn't give a 500 error anymore. But when I try to do svn_update, the logs show this:
     svn_checkout(): svn error(s) occured\n13 (Permission denied) Can't create directory

Comment: PHP is likely running as the `www-data` user, which probably doesn't have write permissions to the folder. You'll need to `chown` the folder to `www-data` or `chmod` it to allow `www-data` to modify.